#    Excel row locking from .Net

Tags: .net, excel

I am generating an Excel spreadsheet from code.  I am trying to customize the cells using .net code,
and I would like to lock the header row so that it won't allow text to be entered into those cells.

I tries following 2 ways with no success

1. worksheet.Range("A1", "A1").EntireRow.Locked = True
2. worksheet.Unprotect()
   worksheet.Range("A1","A100").Locked = True
   worksheet.Protect()

Is that anything I am missing here?

---CODE---

Public Sub CreatNewExcelWithAppliedRules(ByVal noOfWSheets As List(Of String))

```
    Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
    Dim App As New Application
    Dim workbook As Workbook = App.Workbooks.Add()
    Dim worksheet As Worksheet = workbook.Worksheets(1)
    Dim sFile As String = "sample-excel"
    
 
    ---READ HEADERS FROM XML
    Dim xmlFile = "E:\ExcelPOC\ExcelValidation\App_Data\Headers.xml"
    Dim fsReadXml As New System.IO.FileStream(xmlFile, System.IO.FileMode.Open)
    dsHeaders.ReadXml(fsReadXml)
    dtHeader = dsHeaders.Tables("Column")

    ---ADD HEADERS LIST TO EXCEL
    FillColumnHeader(worksheet, dtHeader, culture)

    worksheet.Unprotect()
    ---ADD VALIDATION RULES
    For Each worksheet In workbook.Worksheets
        ListValidExcelRule(worksheet)
        DateValidExcelRule(worksheet)
        TextLengthValidExcelRule(worksheet)
        DecimalValidExcelRule(worksheet)
    Next
    worksheet.Range("1:1").Locked = True
    worksheet.Protect()

    ---SAVE THE EXCEL
     sFile = App.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFilename:=sFile, FileFilter:="xls Files  (*.xls), *.xls")

    If sFile <> "False" Then
        workbook.SaveAs(Filename:=sFile, _
                              FileFormat:=XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, _
                              Password:="", _
                              WriteResPassword:="", _
                              ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, _
                              CreateBackup:=False)
    Else
        App.DisplayAlerts = False
    End If

    workbook.Close(True, misValue, misValue)
    App.Quit()
    releaseObject(worksheet)
    releaseObject(workbook)
    releaseObject(App)

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you receive any errors, or did it simply not prevent edits to the row?

Comment: I didnot receive any errors. it is not applying the locking and allowing to enter text

Answer (score 2):

A1:A100 is the left-hand column.  A1:IV1 is the top row.  Both of your attempts are close.

Try:

```
worksheet.Cells.Locked = False
worksheet.Range("1:1").Locked = True
worksheet.Protect
```

In a new Excel worksheet, all cells are locked by default.  Unless you're unlocking the entire worksheet first, you're better off selecting the cells to unlock rather than the cells to lock.

Comment: I tried the above , but still it is allowing to enter the text in the header

Comment: This works for me when I replace `worksheet` with `worksheets(1)`. You may need to change the index depending on how you generate your Excel file.

Comment: whorksheets are generally stored as a collection of worksheets and you need to tell it which work sheet you wish to lock

Comment: The above code is locking the "Sheet3" that too complete sheet. I want to lock only top row header

Comment: @ramesh, hence my note that all cells are `Locked = True` by default.  I've edited the solution.

Comment: Hand-E-Food , I have tried with your changes. But now nothing is getting locked in first row excel. I verified in all the sheets(1,2,3) defualt generated pages.

Comment: Could be because you use `worksheet` for two separate things in your code - first you set it to a specific sheet, and then you loop through the whole workbook. By the time this code runs, `worksheet` is probably `nothing`.

Comment: I think the problem is with the loop `For Each worksheet In workbook.Worksheets`.  The loop changes the value of `worksheet`.  The `.Locked = True` line is outside this loop when `worksheet` has been changed by the loop.  Move the locking code inside the loop, or write `worksheet = workbook.Worksheets(1)` again.